# Java exception not being caught?

Tags: java, android, oop, exception, try-catch

I´ve got the following code in a class called `UserRepository`, that throws an Exception:

```
public void addUser(final User user) throws  IllegalArgumentException {
        final String encodedUserId = Email.encodeID(user.getEmail().getAddress());
        firebaseUsersRef.child(encodedUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(USER_ALREADY_EXISTS);
                } else {
                    Firebase firebaseUserReference = firebaseRef.child(USERS_TABLE).child(encodedUserId);
                    firebaseUserReference.setValue(user);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(FIREBASE_ERROR);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am using it in `RegisterActivity.java`, like this:

```
public void saveUser(){
     saveUserToDb();
}

private void saveUser(User user) {
        boolean savedUser = false;
        try {
            userRepository.addUser(user);
            savedUser = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            if (iae.getMessage().equals(UserRepository.USER_ALREADY_EXISTS)) {
                showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.user_already_exists));
            } else if (iae.getMessage().equals(UserRepository.FIREBASE_ERROR)) {
                showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_error));
            }
        } finally {
            if (savedUser) {
                showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.new_user_created));
            }
        }
    }
```

So I am catching the exception, if happens. **However, for some reason, the exception is not being caught**.

Any hint?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Here´s my stacktrace:

```
 04-27 09:56:34.984 4741-4741/app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: app, PID: 4741
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User already exists
       at app.repository.UserRepository$1.onDataChange(UserRepository.java:33)
       at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:144)
       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:56)
       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-27 09:57:39.773 4741-4747/app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.473ms
```

Comment: Change IllegalArgumentException to Throwable

Comment: I tried it as well, but it didn´t work

Comment: Did you tried debugging your addUser method?

Comment: Yes. It only says that saveUser is throwing the exception

Comment: Oh man, you're doing it completely wrong. It will never be called!

Comment: Just a suggestion - `IllegalArgumentException` is s runtime exception. Runtime exceptions are usually used when there is a bug in the program that prevents it from running normally. Normally, runtime exceptions are not meant to be caught and processed. To achieve a better design, create your own exception class and propagate it to the next layer of your app.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Many thanks for your comment pal

Comment: You can implement the same thing with your own Custom interface and trigger the functions according to it. Implementing Exceptions and try catch is very heavy task and one should always avoid using try catch

Comment: Can you post the exact error output you get when running your program?

Comment: @YasirTahir I agree with you that try-catch snippets are heavy duty, but I don´t quite get your approach, could you please explain it further?

Comment: @mdewit Sure, I am adding it now

Comment: Ok to me it looks like your code in saveUser is expecting the addUser function to sometimes throw an IllegalArgument exception. However, the addUser function actually never throws  this, only the anonymous ValueEventListener class throws it when its onDataChange function is called. Therefore, it doesnt help to try-catch the addUser function. You need to put the try catch block around the code that calls ValueEventListener.onDataChange()

Comment: @mdewit does that means I am forced to do the error handling there?

Comment: No you dont have to if you do it as explained in Yasir's answer below. I think that will be a better way to do it. The idea is that the onDataChange function will only be called by something other than addUser, therefore you cannot catch its exception when calling addUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing Exceptions and try catch is very heavy task and one should always avoid using try catch. Instead, you can implement the same thing using custom interface and trigger the function according to your requirements. Please see the sample code here:

```
public interface CustomInterface {
  void handleResult(String response);
}
```

Now change your addUser method to:

```
public void addUser(final User user, CustomInterface customInterface){
    final String encodedUserId = Email.encodeID(user.getEmail().getAddress());
    firebaseUsersRef.child(encodedUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                customInterface.handleResult(USER_ALREADY_EXISTS); // I assume this is String
            } else {
                Firebase firebaseUserReference = firebaseRef.child(USERS_TABLE).child(encodedUserId);
                firebaseUserReference.setValue(user);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            customInterface.handleResult(FIREBASE_ERROR); // I assume this is String
        }
    });
}
```

Then finally, change your saveUser Method to:

```
private void saveUser(User user) {
    boolean savedUser = false;
    userRepository.addUser(user, new CustomInterface() {
                @Override
                public void handleResult(String response) {
                    if (response.equals(UserRepository.USER_ALREADY_EXISTS)) {
                        showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.user_already_exists));
                    } else if (response.equals(UserRepository.FIREBASE_ERROR)) {
                        showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_error));
                    }
                    // And Do whatever you want to do, here in this method
                }
            });
}
```

I hope now you'll be able to understand this.

Comment: Good answer pal, thanks. You have been more clear now

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
public void addUser(final User user) {
            final String encodedUserId = Email.encodeID(user.getEmail().getAddress());
            firebaseUsersRef.child(encodedUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        try {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(USER_ALREADY_EXISTS);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Firebase firebaseUserReference = firebaseRef.child(USERS_TABLE).child(encodedUserId);
                        firebaseUserReference.setValue(user);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    try {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(FIREBASE_ERROR);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Comment this line throw new IllegalArgumentException(USER_ALREADY_EXISTS); and this line throw new IllegalArgumentException(FIREBASE_ERROR);

Comment: Why? I don´t want to comment that lines, I want to throw that exceptions

Comment: You can handle the exception there as well without using try catch

Comment: Maybe, but I don´t want to handle it there as long as it´s not a duty of that class